# Docker Container Java System Time Issue

Tags: java, docker

I stumbled upon an issue with Docker container based off of Java wrap my head around it. So here's the code

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.lang.System;
public class UnixTime {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("Now : " + now);
        System.out.println("Unix: " + now.getEpochSecond());
    }
}
```

Once you compile it locally with `javac UnixTime.java` and run it as `java UnixTime` you will get something like this

```
% java UnixTime
Now : 2020-03-19T05:02:19.316Z
Unix: 1584594139
```

Now, let's run it on Docker container based off of `openjdk:8-jre`

```
% docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/myapp -w /usr/myapp openjdk:8-jre java UnixTime
Now : 2020-03-11T17:29:07.368Z
Unix: 1583947747
```

Date and time is completely off. Why is that? Where's it coming from ?

Comment: You may be interested in this discussion: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3359

Comment: it doesn't look like a timezone issue. i tried to change date/time using `date` command but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue, I face the same with openjdk:11 docker image https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/11.0.12-jdk-buster/images/sha256-28bfc95d4437003521bcb122ff5c7c00f35eda7010bd596a1bd5581da7bca7b6?context=explore

Comment: I actually did, there are two ways - one is restart docker daemon. Another one is to run following command (or similar, depending on host os):
`docker run --rm --privileged alpine hwclock -s`
See if that helps in your case